# Get the minimum value of an array

Tags: excel, vba

EDIT:
My target column was typed as "Accounting" and changing it back to "General" was all that was required.  Code works great!  Thanks for the help.

Follow up question, what are some ways (or the best way?) to find the smallest value based on a conditional range?  The list of prices from the database includes product name, type, brand, etc and instead of just finding the lowest price in the database, could it be dynamically changed based on conditional values?  Such as having the target area with drop downs of: Product, brand, type, etc and if blank, give minimum value, and with anything selected such as a certain type or brand, give the lowest value of that specific range?  I switched to using small() instead of min() to find the lowest value so we can find the smallest few values instead of just the 1 lowest.

```
=SMALL(IF([column range of product names]=[cell of target product name]) * ([column of types]=[target type]) * ([column of brands] * [target brand]) * [target brand] <>0 * [target type]<> 0, ([range of product prices]),1)
```

instead of one formula would it be possible or efficient to loop through every row of data to create the desired range then find the minimum value of that newly compiled range?  I figure with only a few dozen rows of data it shouldn't be too bad but with a few hundred would it be too inefficient?  Thanks again for all the help!

Original:
I have a list of prices in a column of variable length that I need to find the lowest value.  I have seen similar questions and people suggesting using min formula but it is not working for my case.

This is for a budget spreadsheet with a list of prices for products with the product name, store, brand, type and I am trying to find the lowest price in the list.  I was running into the issue of even the simplest min function of a list of values so I cannot proceed further with conditions based on certain products or brands or stores.

```
lastrow = sheet3.cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
col = 9

dim rng as variant, min as double
rng = .range(.cells(2,col), .cells(lastrow,col))

min = application.min(rng)
sheet1.cells(1,1) = min
```

When I view locals, I see the rng is correct with all the values from the array range indicated, but the function min always returns 0.  When I input the function on the worksheet of =min(col1:col9) it reveals the correct minimum value.  How can I go about finding the minimum value?  Also I would like to find which row it occurs at, but I assume I can use a find function to do that portion.

Comment: You can just run `Min()` directly on the range

Comment: Your code should work. Did you check your range variable to make sure it is correct?

Comment: Kevin, I was struggling to understand because it seemed like it should work.  Update, I found the column I was trying to determine the smallest value from was typed as "accounting" as $1.99 type and as soon as I changed it to general of course it worked.  I should have checked the formatting

Answer (score 0):

I had to add some items in the code, such as the '`With/End With`' structure, and then I took the opportunity to rename the variables and put `Option Explicit` at the top of the code. I created a test table and got the desired result:

```
Option Explicit

Sub fnGetTheMinValue()
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long
    Dim rng As Variant
    Dim dblMin As Double

    lngLastRow = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lngCol = 9

    With Sheet3
        rng = .Range(.Cells(2, lngCol), .Cells(lngLastRow, lngCol))
    End With
    
    dblMin = Application.min(rng)
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 1) = dblMin

End Sub
```

Comment: Alex, thank you for your help, I realize it is very similar to my original code and I wanted to give an update.  The column of focus was typed as "accounting" aka $1.99 type formatting and would not work.  When I changed it to general, the code worked perfectly.  I should have check that formatting earlier